# Julia: Can ceil/floor return an integer?

Tags: types, julia, floor, ceil

Why don't `ceil()` and `floor()` return an integer? How can I return an integer?

```
a = 10
b = 3
typeof(a/b)
  ## Float64

c = ceil(a/b)
typeof(c)
  ## Float64
```

This issue bothered me in the context of calculating a range, e.g.

```
k = 0:1:c
  ## 0.0:1.0:4.0
typeof(k)
  ## StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}
```

Full disclosure: I think I have an answer, so I'm going to answer my own question, however please do post an answer if you have a better one. Hopefully next time someone looks, they'll find an answer easily here.

Comment: One thing to consider for this specific case is that Julia provides `cld`, `div`, and `fld` to compute `ceil(Int, a/b)`, `round(Int, a/b)` and `floor(Int, a/b)` using only integer arithmetic, which is likely faster and also won't run into rounding issues.

Comment: you also got `÷` (typed by \div then tab) to do the integer division.

Comment: Very good to know Oscar and 张实唯 . Feel free to add an answer. Or I can add the info to my answer, as you prefer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At times you want `ceil()` and `floor()` to return something other than an integer, e.g. `Inf`, `NaN`. However, you can return an integer like this:

```
julia> c = ceil(Int64, a/b)
julia> typeof(c)
Int64 

julia> k = 0:1:c
0:1:4

julia> typeof(k)
StepRange{Int64, Int64}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.ceil)